# Send post request using restsharp thru proxy

Tags: c#, http, restsharp

Im trying to send a post request thru a proxy using restsharp but i dont know how to. im not trying to send it thru a proxy that requires authentication( ip authentication or user/pass) just a simple ip:port proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify proxy in the client options:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(url) { 
    Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress)
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Comment: Yeah it seems setting it directly on _client.Options.Proxy has no effect (should this be made read only?)

Comment: Yeah, two choices - hide the options or make it read only. It used to be a record type and it was init-only but people who use old SDKs have troubles with it. It’s made read only in v109 latest preview.

Comment: Is there any way it could just the system default proxy automatically like browsers and other apps do? That way, simply running fidder would just work without external "useFiddlerProxy: true" being needed.  It would need to be opt-in for security, so you could have something like `if (env == Environment.Development) options.UseDefaultProxy = true;`

Comment: RestSharp just passes the options to HttpClient and HttpMessageHandler, so I can suggest looking at the Microsoft docs to figure it out.